# How to copy file in Docker?

Tags: docker, sonarqube, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM sonarqube

RUN wget https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar
COPY sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

And I get the following error while copying the file:

```
Removing intermediate container 63a3ae1d7390
Step 3/3 : COPY sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
lstat sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar: no such file or directory
```

How can I copy the file in this case?

Comment: Same error when I replace with ADD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to copy a file located in your container as if it was a local file, so Docker is unable to find it.

Use ADD like this should make it work :

```
FROM sonarqube

ADD https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

it's more "dockerlike"

Answer (score 1):

You're running `wget` inside the container, but then trying to `COPY` it from the *host* machine to the container. To copy from one container location to another simply use `cp`:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar \
 && cp sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

Better yet, just use `wget -O` to save the file in the desired location from the get go.

```
RUN wget -o /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ \
        https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` command copies file from the host to the container.
For any command you want to run inside the container you need `RUN`:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar \
   && cp sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```